# How to access child element via wdio

Tags: webdriver-io

Below code is for finding parent. What needs to be passed instead of ".." to access child?

`const parent = paragraph.$('..')`

`console.log(parent.getTagName())` // outputs: "body"

Answer (score 4):

Do you know which elements are you looking for? Check these examples:

```
paragraph.$$('//*')      // find all childs
paragraph.$('a')         // find first child link
paragraph.$('*=Submit')  // find first child element which contains 'Submit'
```

You can use any locator strategy as you want - `CSS`, `XPath`, `TagName` or by `text`. Check [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors.html)